# subdomains w/o TLD

Tags: apache2, subdomain

How do i set up a subdomain w/o a TLD? i have this set under my main config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bbs.67.777.777.777 #fake bc my server can easily be hacked ATM :(
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpBB
</VirtualHost>
```

when i goto bbs.serveripaddress i get a Address Not Found error. if i put that above my main config it still doesnt work however the entire site is pointing to /var/www/phpBB instead of /var/www (HUH!?!)

the main v host is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
                # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
                RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm on a debian box using apache2 if that helps.

Comment: That's not a programming question - more of a system admin or IT question.  This is not the best forum for this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a subdomain with an IP address. The best way around this is to have a domain or a free subdomain (such as no-ip) to point at your IP address and create a ServerName for that. Remember to add the domain to your server DNS zones.

or make a domain in your host files and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that server name (bbs.67.777.777.777 ) will get you anywhere - unless you have it added to your hosts file...  Can you ping that address ok?

Why not just make your website the default... if you don't need a default?

Comment: correct, if you just have a ip address (67.777.777.777) you can't use name-based virtual hosts. You need some kind of dns (but it can be .local on a intranet).